# Rails pluck undefined method `gallery' for "nmnm":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to use pluck but because of carrierwave gallery images
this error is showing in the logs

```
undefined method `gallery' for "nmnmnnmn":String
```

So this method is working OK

```
 @boats = Boat.limit(12).order('created_at DESC').includes([:gallery]).all
```

But as per see i would like to reduce the memory footprint using pluck

```
  @boats = Boat.order(created_at: :desc).includes(:gallery).limit(16).pluck("boats.name")
```

and as know the pluck change to array, so why the gallery still a method with pluck?

Comment: probably somewhere in your code, that is not shown in your question, you're calling the method 'gallery' on a boat object, and it's working. But when you use pluck, you're not returning boat objects, but an array of strings of boat names, so you can't call the gallery method on the value returned by the second query.

Answer (score 1):

As you already stated in your question, `pluck` returns an array, so you can't call `gallery` on the resulting objects, which are just strings in this case. Because of this, `includes(:gallery)` does nothing here, except adds unnecessary overhead to your query, since you cannot access the associated `gallery` objects.

If you want to keep the result of your query as small as possible while retaining model functionality, you could use [select](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select) to only get the fields you need. `select` will return an ActiveRecord object, so all the methods associated with the model will work normally, as long they don't require any of the fields you left out. Note that if you want to eager load the associated `gallery`, you should also select `gallery_id` (or whatever columns are necessary for the association to work).

```rb
@boats = Boat.includes(:gallery).order(created_at: :desc).limit(16).select(:name, :gallery_id)
```